# MVVM Light templates not showing in "Add Item" menu (VS 2017)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2017, nuget, mvvm-light

I've installed MVVM Light Toolkit through NuGet in VS 2017. The problem is that when I click "Add New Item" on any project, I don't see any MVVM templates that appear in MVVM Light tutorials.

They must look like this (but I don't see them in my project):
http://prntscr.com/n9bs1q

I found similar questions about VS 2012. The answers advise to search for C:\Program Files (x86)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Vsix

But I have no such folder not in Program Files (x86), neither in Program Files.

Help me please, what should I do for the templates to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM Light NuGet can only add related resources (assemblies/.cs files) into the project. It wont add Templates into Visual Studio. To get templates in Visual Studio, you have to install MVVM Light Visual Studio Extension by following the below steps.

1. Open Visual Studio and go to `Tools->Extensions and Updates`.
2. In the `Extensions and Updates` window lick `Online` in the left pane.
3. In the search bar, type `MVVM Light`.
4. In the search results find `MVVM Light for VS2017`. Click Download and accept license.

Extension will be installed once Visual Studio gets restarted. Then you can get the templates.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

They have stopped support of `Item Templates for MVVM Light` in Visual Studio 2017. Its been there up to VS 2015. So you can only get Project Templates (File->New Project) in VS 2017 extension. You can see similar queries [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentBugnion.MVVMLightforVS2017&ssr=false#qna).

[image]

Comment: Did this all and still no MVVM Light templates in "Add new item" menu.....(

http://prntscr.com/n9kkbh

Comment: Can you see the MVVM Light Project Templates in File->New Project window? Is the extension installed properly? Check it in Tools->Extensions and Updates->Installed.

Comment: yes, I can see MVVM Light templates in "New Project" window! But the "funny" thing is that even if I create a new MvvmLight(WPF451) project, inside of it, if I click "Add New Item", there are no MVVM templates.

And yes, "MVVM Light VS2017" is listed in the "Installed" section of "Extensions and Update".

May be there is some manual way to check if MVVM Light element templates are actually installed?

Comment: Yes, After spent some time, I have confirmed that MVVM Light Item Templates are not available for Visual Sudio 2017. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. If I had enough reputation, I would rate it

Comment: Thank you. Still you can mark it as answer if its resolves your issue.